# Getting failed delivery emails using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm parsing failed delivery emails and then logging it to database for sending again, but it's failing on preg_match section. I'm sure that pattern is correct, many times checked on regex101.com, but the result of function is always false.

```
$inbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $username, $pass) or die('Cannot connect to gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'SINCE ' . $since);
$invalidEmails = array();
if ($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email, 1);
        if(preg_match("/^Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:\n\n\s+(.+)/im", $message, $matches)) {
            Debugger::log("mail found");
        }

        array_push($invalidEmails, $matches);

        if(preg_match("/^Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:\n\n\s+(.+)/im", $message, $matches)) {
            Debugger::log("mail found");
        }

        array_push($invalidEmails, $matches);
    }
}

imap_close($inbox);
```

Content of $message:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     123@blabla.com

Technical details of permanent failure:=20
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for=
```

I have been stuck with this few hours, can somebody know what could be a problem?

Comment: What result do you get if you change your first pattern to `"/^Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:\s+(.+)/im"`?

Comment: Thank you, stupid mistake -_-

Comment: If I could have helped you fix your issue, it's my pleasure. Generally, matching line separator with '\n' may cause some problems and you better care about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
preg_match("/^Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:\n\n\s+(.+)/im", $message, $matches)
```

by

```
preg_match("/^Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:\s+(.+)/im", $message, $matches)
```